# Which of the following is the most appropriate meaning of the word " a red-letter" day?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The question came in one of my examinations and I've been getting different answers from different sources. The options of the question were:
a) a day of memory
b) a day of festival
c) an important day

I'm confused between the options a and c above since different dictionaries have highlighted one of the above two options as the answers. Will really appreciate if someone can help me out here.

Comment: Bad choices in the question. Many questions are incorrect, even on national exams.

Answer (score 4):

The origin of *red-letter day* is the custom of printing the names of festivals in red in prayer book calendars. The custom started with manuscript calendars, but it still happens with modern books.

[image: "23 Mary Magdalene" and "25 James the Apostle" shown in red among other significant dates shown in black]
(Image of July from *Common Worship,* pub. 2000)

Thus it's entirely reasonable for the term *red-letter day* to refer to a day of festival, a day of rejoicing.

OED includes this meaning:

> **red-letter day**  *n.*  (a) (originally) a saint's day or other Christian festival conventionally indicated in the calendar by red letters;  (b) (now also *figurative*) any significant, memorable, or happy day;

Thus **all** of your potential meanings are entirely valid, and what is more appropriate in any case must depend on what is being described. What it actually should mean in your case is unclear, because you have provided no context.

Comment: Thank you for the response Sir. Actually the examination consisted of multiple choice questions and in this particular question no context was provided at all. It is conducted by the highest ranking Institute in my country and decision of the Institute regarding the answer can not be challenged under any circumstances. Since no context has been provided, the Institute expects us to mark the option that will be the closest meaning among the options.

Comment: Sir, if you were to select the most appropriate answer from the above options with no context provided. What would you select.

Comment: What it means to *me* is "a day of festival", a happy day, a day of rejoicing. But since this comes from a test, the right answer is what the examiners say it is, not what I would put.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Sir. The question seems unfair without context.

Comment: Yes, this is one of those multiple-choice examination questions that native speakers would be in great danger of failing. Unlike @AndrewLeach I would select "An important day" so at least one of us would be wrong. "A day of memory" is a strange way of writing the third option, I assume they mean "A memorable day" and, if they do, it's another reasonable meaning, I wouldn't choose it myself but I suspect that around a third of the native speaker population would. It's a horribly unfair and badly written question with no clear answer in my opinion.

Comment: Also, shouldn't be confused with a *red nose day*  https://nationaltoday.com/red-nose-day/

Comment: I'd guess "A day of memory" means a day for remembering, like Holocaust Memorial Day. But it's certainly not cut-and-dried. And possibly some red-letter days in the Christian calendar would match that (e.g. All Souls' Day, which Wikipedia calls "a day of prayer and remembrance for the faithful departed"). Still, "a day of memory" is not the best match.

Answer (score 2):

"A red-letter day" means *c, an important day*. It may be a memorable day because it is important, but the importance is primary.

[Merriam-Webster *red-letter day*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/red-letter%20day)
informal
: a very happy and important day